# How can I get rows that present outliers for the column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis

First I needed to create a function that returns True when the z-score is lower than -3 or larger than 3, and False otherwise. Then apply that function to dataframe. But now
I want to show the rows that present outliers for the column stand_Gross.SqFt. subset by passing the outliers series. How do I do that? Everything I tried is for numeric and this is a string function (true/false).

```
def zscore (x):
    if (x > 3):
        return 'True'
    elif (x < -3):
        return 'True'
    else :
        return 'False'
```

applying the function to dataframe:

```
housing['stand_Gross.SqFt'].apply(zscore)
```

Answer (score 0):

you do not want to do "apply" as you slow your code way down

start with

```
housing['is_outlier'] = housing['stand_Gross.SqFt'] > 3
# print outliers
print(housing[housing['is_outlier']])
```

you can of coarse simply skip the first step

```
outliers = housing[housing['stand_Gross.SqFt'] > 3]
print(outliers)
```

Comment: no but i need to use apply function in the code. Also what will be the final outlier series ?

Comment: But now I want to show the rows that present outliers for the column stand_Gross.SqFt. subsetting by passing the outliers series.